# How to use a ERB file in Ruby to write some text in a text file

Tags: ruby, erb

I have a play.erb file:

```
<p>Welcome!<br><p>
<% if $wgplaying==true %>
        Template: <%= $template %>
<% end %>
<br><br>

<% if $wginword==true && $wgplaying==true && $a!='' %>
        Character <%= $a %> is in word.
<% end %>

<% if $wginword==false && $wgplaying==true && $a!='' %>
        Character <%= $a %> is not in word.
<% end %>   

<br><br>
```

I want to write

```
"Character <%= $a %> is in word."
```

or

```
"Character <%= $a %> is not in word."
```

in a text file, but I do not know what command should I use. Or, should I do this in a Ruby file?

Comment: Try running your script with erb, then redirect to a text file: `erb play.erb > file.txt`.

Comment: How you evaluate ERB from within a Ruby script is first `require 'erb'` then `ERB.new(text).result(binding)`. Either that or the command line utility will work

Comment: Also, it would be customary to use 2 extensions, in this case: `your_erb_template.txt.erb`

Answer (score 3):

ERB is in Ruby's Standard Library, so try something like this:

```
require 'erb'

TEMPLATE_FILE = 'template.erb'

$wgplaying = true
$template = "This is my template"
$wginword = true
$wgplaying = true
$a = "something"

render = ERB.new(File.read(TEMPLATE_FILE),trim_mode: ">")
puts render.result
```

The [`new`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.6.5/libdoc/erb/rdoc/ERB.html#method-c-new) method has many options.

These are the `trim_mode` options:

```
%  enables Ruby code processing for lines beginning with %
<> omit newline for lines starting with <% and ending in %>
>  omit newline for lines ending in %>
-  omit blank lines ending in -%>
```